# Bringing souvenirs for other through UK Customs to give on board ship?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

Our group is on the first transatlantic cruise on a new ship leaving from Southampton in April.  I have designed lapel pins and will order them from a company for others in the group that have ordered and paid me for. I will be bringing them through the airport and onto the ship to give to the people who bought them.  The cruise ends in New York, NY and I, and many others, will return to our homes in the US from there.  While each pin itself is only going to be about $5.00 the total amount ordered will go over $700.  How do I declare these pins at the border and will I need to pay anything to customs?

Answer (score 1):

You're arriving to connect to a vessel at a UK port, the value of each item is small, and, in effect, you are a courier, taking each to the individual who has purchased it (you were the coordinator).

While you'll be taking with you large quantity of one item, and the total value may appear to be excess, monitarily, for goods brought into the UK, they're not for your personal use, gifts, for commercial purposes, and the items will not remain in the UK.

It is not likely that they would be considered dutiable, and you should be able to go through the Customs Nothing to Declare green exit.